# global functions dont work with tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter

I wrote a basic script in Python3 to create a basic function that would display then close a window. I would like to have a function to close the window, so I could import the script into a different file I have without cluttering it up too much. I tried this, however the compiler returns with `name tkdel() is not defined`.

```
def tkdisp(t): 
    import tkinter as tk
    class disp(tk.Frame): 
        def __init__(self, master=None): 
            super().__init__(master) 
            self.pack() 
            self.distk = tk.Label(self) 
            self.distk["text"] = t
            self.distk.pack(side="top") 
            root = tk.Tk()
            disp(master=root).mainloop()
            def tkdel():
              global tkdel
              root.destroy
tkdisp('nice')
tkdel()
```

Comment: I found the above code to be structured in a very _uncommon_ way.

Comment: The function `tkdel` will only exist inside the scope of `disp.__init__`.

Comment: @Nae its structured for readability, mainly because I prefer that when showing code to others. I will admit it is very odd.

Comment: @0x5453 any way to expand the scope?

Comment: Any way to expand the scope? Sure: don't put the function inside another function. In most cases the only thing it does is make your code harder to write and harder to understand. Also, by putting the code after `mainloop()`, the function won't be defined until after `mainloop()` exits, which means after the root window has been destroyed. At that point you'll just get an error if you try to destroy it again.

Comment: @BryanOakley And how may I do that, defining `root`  globally and in a function before `mainloop()`?  Apologies, I just started Python.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

well I had to change the code quite a bit but this works (Hope it helps):

```
import tkinter as tk

root = tk

class disp(tk.Frame): 
    def __init__(self, master=None): 
        super().__init__(master) 
        self.pack() 
        self.distk = tk.Label(self) 
        self.distk["text"] = t
        self.distk.pack(side="top") 
        root = tk.Tk()
        disp(master=root).mainloop()
    def tkdel():
      #global tkdel
      app = None
      exit()

disp.tkdel()
```

I try to not use globals too much as it can get complicated in a big program. :) it's better to send data between places directly. :)

I just reread the question. If you want to use another *FILE* - like file.py you can import the file on startup just by saying: **import file**

If you want to close the window from anywhere just use **disp.tkdel()** as this is a direct path. Really hope this helps. :)